# Change subdomain links in database

Tags: mysql, database, subdomain, cpanel

I want to move my applications hosted on one subdomain to another subdomain. I've moved all files, but I don't know how to change links in database. In cPanel, I have phpMyAdmin, MySQL Databases, MySQL Database Wizard and RemoteMySQL. Can you help me?

Comment: What's your web application?

Answer (score 1):

Go to PHPMyAdmin and select your database. Then browse through database tables. Here you can change column values (i.e. subdomain links). Your problem is application oriented. If you comment your application name, then i can help you in better way.